# Is this the proper way to set up VPN tunnels for this network topology?

Tags: cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

Below is the network topology I will be working with. The left just shows that all sites have a single internet connection. The right shows how I would be setting up the VPN tunnels. The main concern for these sites is that if the internet connection to site 1 goes down the other sites will still have access to site 2. This is needed so the phones will continue to work.

[image]

Just wanting to get some input on if there is a better way to do this or some pitfalls I should look out for.

Comment: Site 1 and site 2 have distinct IP ranges so that you can split between them with crypto maps, right?  And will there ever be any need for sites 3, 4, and 5 to talk to each other?  An MPLS or DMVPN deployment may preserve your sanity a bit better than this if you need anything more complicated than to have the bottom 3 sites talk to specific networks at sites 1 and 2 - your link between 1 and 2 would imply that it's more complicated than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the connections WAN connections but also indicate they are Internet connections. Which is it?  If they are WAN connections, you should look into Metro-Ethernet. Metro-E links at each site will create a mesh so that all sites can talk to one-another regardless of any one site going down. 
 If they are Internet connections - yeah that ought to work but you wouldn't necessarily need the extra link between sites 1 and 2 unless you wanted it.

Comment: Every site just has a internet connection, no metero-e, mpls, etc. There are servers at site 1 and site 2 so that is why there would be a L2L VPN between them. I guess I should have been more clear. L2L VPNS are the only option I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something the ASA could offer that was better then the L2L VPN route.

Comment: not that I'm aware of.